# Unable to connect to MongoDB 6.0 (on oracle cloud free tier) through Compass via SSH - 'All configured authentication methods failed' error

Tags: mongodb, ssh, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, mongodb-compass

I recently got myself an Oracle Cloud free tier compute VM, mainly for experimenting and development. This is running Ubuntu 22.04.
I've installed MongoDB Community 6.0 on here. I'm able to do R/W on it with my standard approaches (Python/Mongosh) directly from a login shell, but I typically rely on Compass (with SSH tunelling from my laptop) to make sense of the data I have in a given Mongo instance.

Now, I've configured everything in Compass the way I'd expect to do it:

- the username I use to log into Mongo, as well as the PW
- the IP address of the oracle machine that I use for SSH-ing into the machine, along with the ssh-key I use for ssh-ing; associated with the username I log into on the machine.
- This is MongoDB Compass version 1.34.0 running on MacOs 12.4

[image]

However, I'm unable to access the MongoDB instance through compass. I followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-remote-access-for-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04) to allow access on the MongoDB port for ufw.

It's also important to note, I think, that running `hostname -I` results in a different IP than the one I use to SSH into the machine -- it's the IP which is listed in the oracle cloud console as my 'private IP'. I tried subbing this IP into the SSH Hostname field in the field with the screenshot, and rather than immediately giving me the 'All configured authentication methods failed' error, it opens the connection window, and then fails with a timeout error message.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could do to make this work?

- maybe some kind of whitelisting in the oracle cloud admin site?
- maybe I need to allow some kind of connection in the mongodb config file on the machine?
- might there be an issue in using the same ssh key as for regular ssh-ing through a terminal?
- in past similar setups, I always used MongoDB version 4.4. Might there be an issue with using version 6 in Compass?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.